# Consider `var = 5`, would the value `5` be automatically dedeted by the computer once I re-assign another value to `var`?

Tags: python, ubuntu, out-of-memory, cpu

Let's consider a simple situation,

```
var = 5
var = 6
```

The first line assign `5` to `var` and the next line re-assign `6` to `var`. Just out of curiosity, whether the value `5` would be automatically removed from the CPU's memory or not? If not, then would the following python code, in theory, blow up my computer due to memory comsuption?

```
var = 5
while True:
    var = var + 1
```

Comment: It's a lot more complicated than that -- no, Python doesn't allocate more memory for every reassignment, but at the same time, it also doesn't release memory back to the OS; it just frees up memory for *other uses inside the Python interpreter itself*.

Comment: There is garbage collection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)

Comment: https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/

Comment: Thank you all. According to the two links given above, I think the answer should lie in the mechanism of python's garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `var` is no longer keeping its previous value from being removed from memory at that point. In CPython (the usual implementation of Python):

- that even usually happens as soon as you reassign `var` because CPython uses reference counting
- that won’t happen for 5 specifically because CPython keeps a certain range of small integers in memory at all times

Your loop won’t fill up memory with old ints in any reasonable Python implementation. In practice, it uses a small, bounded amount of memory.

> in theory

In theory, Python has arbitrary size ints, so you’ll use (for example) 2 GB of memory after 2<sup>16,000,000,000</sup> loop iterations. You’ll never come close to running out of memory for this reason, because there’s not enough time in the universe to get there.

Answer (score 1):

You would get integer overflow before consuming all your computer's memory *if this example were done without Pure Python (e.g. Pandas/NumPy)*. Pure Python 3 has an `int` type that theoretically stores arbitrarily long integers; however there's still a limit on your computer's available memory. Python does the memory management in the background, and this reassignment doesn't hold onto the value 5 in memory after the variable is reassigned.

In essence:

```py
var = 5 # var is 5 and its address is managed for you
var = 6 # the value that var points to is now 6, there's no record of 5 anymore.
```

so when you do the full loop:

```py
var = 5
while True:
    var = var + 1 # This is reassignment of the value at the address -- NOT bloating memory
```

Comment: "You would get integer overflow" not a thing in Python, which uses arbitrary-sizee integers